# Windows 8 requirements for developing Store apps

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am new Windows store development. Can i use Windows 8 Enterprise Evaluation 32-bit (x86) version or any restrictions to use only 64-bit version
Waiting for your valuable reply.
Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the 32bit version of Windows 8 myself and it works fine.  There is such a restriction for Win Phone 8 apps, but for Win 8 you're fine on x86.

Comment: Right now i have Windows8 Release preview. But it is not working fine with Visual studio 2012 for store apps. That's way i go for Enterprise edition.Is it is recommended for Windows store apps?

Comment: No - the release preview has some differences.  You need a full version of Windows 8.  Enterprise will allow you to develop apps.

Answer (score 0):

Both x86 and x64 (32-bit and 64-bit) operating systems are supported. There is only 32-bit version of Visual Studio 2012 available, and it can be installed on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: Thank you, Right now i have Windows8 Release preview. But it is not working fine with Visual studio 2012 for store apps. That's way i go for Enterprise edition.Is it is recommended for Windows store apps?